# Given $y\in \mathbb{R}^n$, what is the solution set of $|x|=|y|$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ when $n\geq 3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, multivariable-calculus, linear-transformations

Fix $y\in \mathbb{R}^n$, what is the solution of $|x|=|y|$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ when $n\geq 3$ ?

In dimension $n=1$ we have $x=\pm y$ and in dimension $n=2$ we also easily see that $x=O y$ where $O$ is a rotation matrix (an orthogonal matrix).

The solution set is obviously non-empty in dimensions $n\geq 3$. It contains the vectors $x=O y$ where $O$ in an $n-$dimensional rotation matrix.

What is the complete solution ?

Comment: I guess this will be unsatifying, but it is the bundary of the ball of center $0$ and radius $|y|$. If $\mathbb S^{n-1}$ is the unit circle of $\mathbb R^n$, this is also $|y|\mathbb S^{n-1}$. Finally, if your norm $|\cdot|$ comes from an inner product, this is the set of $u(y)$ where $u \in O(\mathbb R^n)$.

Comment: The solution is the same for any natural number $n$: $\|x\|=\|y\|$ if and only if $x=Oy$ for some orthogonal matrix $O$. I don't understand why is it that you introduce those transformations $y\mapsto Ay+B$.

Comment: For any vector $x \in \mathbb R^n$, we have $x = Iy + (x-y)$ where $I$ is the identity matrix. Note that your series of biconditionals implies that two vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ have the same norm if and only if they are the same vector, which is certainly untrue (it is your first biconditional that is wrong).

Comment: First at all you should define what $|x|$ is when $x\in\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: @ José Carlos Santos Thank you prof. Santos. Could you please show how $\|x\|=\|y\| \implies x=Oy$ for some orthogonal matrix $O$ ?

Comment: @Zag. Your comment was helpful (+1).

Comment: @Piquito. Take $|x|:=\sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle}$  with the usual inner product on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ as already used in the question!

Comment: @Medo: any point in the sphere centered at the origin and if radius $|y|$ is a solution and vice versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume that $|x| = \sqrt{x^T x}$ here. Complete a basis of $\mathbb R^n$ with $y$ as the first vector. We may assume (by possibly carrying out Gram-Schmidt) that this basis is orthonormal, so that the matrix $Y$ whose columns are the elements of this basis is an orthogonal/rotation matrix. For any vector $x \in \mathbb R^n$, extend $x$ to a basis of $\mathbb R^n$, which, as before, we may assume to be orthonormal. Let $X$ be the matrix whose columns are the elements of this basis, so $X$ is orthogonal. Note that $Y$ sends the first standard basis vector to $y/|y|$ and $X$ sends the first standard basis vector to $x/|x|$. Then $XY^{-1}$, which is also orthogonal, sends $y/|y|$ to $x/|x|$ and hence sends $y$ to $x \cdot |y|/|x|$. In particular, if $|x|=|y|$, then $XY^{-1}$ sends $y$ to $x$. Conversely, if there exists an orthogonal matrix $O$ with $Oy=x$, then
$$|x| = \sqrt{x^T x} = \sqrt{y^TO^TOy} = \sqrt{y^TIy} = \sqrt{y^Ty} = |y|$$
so indeed the set of vectors $x$ with $|x|=|y|$ is precisely the set of vectors $Oy$ with $O$ orthogonal, as José's comment suggests.

Comment: If $|x| = |y|$, then $x = Oy$, where $O = XY^{-1}$.

Comment: Is there a systemic mechanism to generate a maximal linearly independent set starting from one given vector ?